# [OLVED. Error getting data from POST ajax petition Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

It has been a rough night and morning today hahaha. I'm trying to get some `data` with `symfony2` from an `AJAX` `'POST'` petition.

Actually I want to sent an array and get it in the controller but I'm receiving an error like this variable is `null`. I think I'm trying to get it in a right way but... **Let's take a look!**

**This is the JS AJAX petition, I'm getting the ul#sortable.children() order to update it on the dataBase, so I sent an array with the position and id.**

> example: ["1", "3", "2"]. So the object with id=1 in the db is going to be in the position 1. The element with id=3 is going to be in the position 2 and the element with id=2 is going to be in the position 3.

```
$('#ordenar').click(function(){
            var $children = $('#sortable').children();
            var numElementos = $children.length;
            var socialSorted = [];

            for(var i=0; i<numElementos; i++){
                socialSorted.push($children[i].id);
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: ' {{ path('admin_update_social_position') }} ',
                datos: socialSorted,
                method: 'POST'
            }).done(function (data) {
                if(data.type == 'OK'){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                if(data.type == 'ERROR'){
                    $('#error-message').slideDown();
                }
            });
        });
```

**And here is the controller**

```
/**
     * @Route("/admin/update/order/social", name="admin_update_social_position")
     */
    public function orderSocial(Request $request)
    {
        $em             = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $socialSorted   = $request->request->get('socialSorted');
        $numElementos   = count($socialSorted);

        for($i=0; $i<$numElementos; $i++)
        {
            $social = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Social')->findById($socialSorted[$i]);
            $social->setPosition($i+1);
            $em->persist($social);
        }

        if (empty($socialSorted)) {
            $this->sendResponseStatus('ERROR');

            return new JSONResponse($this->getData());
        }

        $em->flush();

        $this->sendResponseStatus('OK');

        // Generamos los datos para la respuesta ajax
        return new JSONResponse($this->getData());
    }
```

I tried many ways... sending the array, sending a `JSON` with an array in and also different ways to get the data from the `controller`... any advice/solution?

**Thanks you to all of you**

**EDIT: The error was in the lines**

```
$social = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Social')->findById($socialSorted[$i]);
            $social->setPosition($i+1);
            $em->persist($social);
```

Becausee after findBy it returns you and arrayCollection and then I should do:

```
$social = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Social')->findById($socialSorted[$i]);
                $social[0]->setPosition($i+1);
                $em->persist($social[0]);
```

Comment: `datos: socialSorted,`... datos? ... Shouldn't it be `data: socialSorted,`? The fact that you get `null` indicates that the param is NOT being sent correctly. Symfonys `request->get()` returns `null` if the param doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, correct me if am wrong. In ajax, you have written `datos` instead of `data` and also send the data with a keyname. Like this

`data: { 'socialSorted' : socialSorted},`

Comment: Agree! Yes! What a huge mistake.. hahah thank you to all! I'm receiving an internal error now but I'll take a look to the controller!! @KinshukLahiri

Comment: @KinshukLahiri anyway, I corrected it but I still having error in the Controller.. this line: $socialSorted   = $request->request->get('socialSorted'); is not giving me the data... because I'm printing it and its null :/ Do you know why?

Comment: @VictorRiberoGuasch Any input you have got?

Comment: I send an array to the controller like ["1", "3", "2"] and the controller has to, get the element by id 1 and update an Entity attribute with the position of this array (in this case 0). Then,  the register with id=3 update this attribute to 3 and the element with id=2 update the attribute to 3 but I'm getting and error.. and I don' t know why. @KinshukLahiri

Comment: the poblem are $social->setPosition($i+1);
            $em->persist($social); inside the "for" because if I delete them It doesn't return an error.. @KinshukLahiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: ' {{ path('admin_update_social_position') }} ',
            data: {
                socialSorted: socialSorted,
            },
            method: 'POST'
        }).done(function (data) {
            if(data.type == 'OK'){
                window.location.reload();
            }
            if(data.type == 'ERROR'){
                $('#error-message').slideDown();
            }
        });
```

You need to send the data as an array. You ask for `socialSorted` key in request, but actually you don't send it

Comment: anyway, I corrected it but I still having error in the Controller.. this line: $socialSorted   = $request->request->get('socialSorted'); is not giving me the data... because I'm printing it and its null :/ Do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

The problem here lies in the fact that you are expecting a `socialSorted` variable from AJAX but never getting it:

In controller:
`$socialSorted = $request->get('socialSorted');`

But in AJAX call..
`datos: socialSorted,`

In your controller, just make it read...
`$socialSorted = $request->get('datos');` or change the AJAX call to `socialSorted: socialSorted`